# Find column and row name based on search criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
      A            B     C        D      E            F            G
1                 Q1     Q2      Q3     Q4   Search criteria:     60
2   Asset 1       15     85      90     70   Column name:         Q4
3   Asset 2       40     80      45     60   Row name:          Asset 2
4   Asset 3       30     50      55     10
5
```

In `Cells A1:E4` I have different assets with their performance from quarter `Q1-Q4`. 
In `Cell G2` and `G3` I want that the assets and the quarter are displayed based on the value that is put in `Cell G1`. 
In this case the search criteria is `60` so the result is column name `Q4` and row name `Asset 2`.

---

With **VLOOKUP** or **INDEX** & **MATCH** I would only be able to find the the value `60` based on the criterias in `Cell G2` and `G3` but not the other way around like I need it.

---

Do you have any idea of a formula that could solve this issue?

**NOTE:** All values in the table are unique.

Comment: You should nest 4 index match's to search the columns in an IF statement. If you find a value > 0 then you know the right Quarter, and you also have the relative row numbre at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

G2:

```
=INDEX(B1:E1,MATCH(G1,INDEX(B2:E4,MATCH(G3,A2:A4,0),0),0))
```

G3, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER:

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,SMALL(IF(B2:E4=G1,ROW(A2:A4)-ROW(A2)+1),1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this (entered as array formulas using Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

[image]