# Find column name based on search criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A        B         C              D              E          F       
1     MFC2      MFC1      QFC      Search Criteria:     CW14
2     CW11                         Column Name:         MFC1
3               CW13   
4               CW14 
5                        CW17
6                        CW18
7                        CW19
8
9
```

In `Cells A1:C8` I have different calender weeks. All of them are **unique**!
In `Cell E2` I want that the `column name` is displayed based on the value that is put in `Cell E1`. 
 
In this case the search criteria is `CW14` so the result should be column name `MFC1`.

---

I tried to modify the formula from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52486216/find-column-and-row-name-based-on-search-criteria) question but could not make it work:

```
E1 = INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(E$1,$A$2:$C$30,0))
```

This formula gives me `#NV` as result. 
What do I need to change to get the desried result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE instead of MATCH:

```
=INDEX(1:1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN($A$2:$C$30)/($A$2:$C$30=$E$1),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I change the matrix from A1:C8 to for example to G16:I23 the formula gives me #REF. What do I need to change to make it independent from the position of the matrix within the sheet: =INDEX(G16:I16,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN($G$17:$I$45)/($G$17:$I$45=$E$1),1))

Comment: keep the full row as the first criterion:  `INDEX(16:16,...`

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MAX(ISNUMBER(FIND(E1,$A$2:$C$7))*COLUMN($A$2:$C$7)))
```

[image]