# Find column name based on search criteria (if the values are only unique per row)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A          B           C         D          E           F            G
1   FC-Week      FC1.1      FC1.2      FC1.3      FC1.4      FC-Week      FC-CW02
2   FC-CW01      CW02       CW03       CW04       CW05       CW-Week      CW04
3   FC-CW02      CW03       CW04       CW05       CW06       FC-Number    ???
4   FC-CW03      CW04       CW05       CW06       CW07
5   FC-CW04      CW05       CW06       CW07       CW08
6   FC-CW05      CW06       CW07       CW08       CW09
7
9
```

`Row 1` contains the column headers of the table. 
`Column A` contains the row headers of the table. 
In `Cells B2:E6` are the values in the table.

**NOTE:** The values are unique per row!

---

Now, in `Cell G3` I want to get the `column header in Row 1` based on the search criterias in `Cell G1` and `G2`. 
As far as I can see I have to go with two steps.

**a)** Get the row-number of the criteria in `Cell G1`. I used this formula: `=MATCH(G1,A:A,0)` 
**b)** Based on the row number from **a)** I need a formula that finds the column of the criteria in `Cell G2` and then gets the header of it (in the example the result would be `FC1.2`)

I tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60283639/find-column-name-based-on-search-criteria) but I guess it only works if the values in the array are unique.

What formula do I need to achive the described result in **b)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH to return the correct row to the MATCH:

```
=INDEX(A1:E1,,MATCH(G2,INDEX(A:E,MATCH(G1,A:A,0),0),0))
```

[image]