# Look for a value in more than one column and get the corresponding address

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to look for a value(text value) in the entire worksheet and get the `row` and `column` number of the cell which contain this value? I plan to use this `column` number to retrieve a value in this column. We suppose that there is only one instance of the value we are looking for.

It seems like when using `Match` function we've got to know which column to look for in, but in my case this column is unknown.

Comment: index() with match() will do this, lots of examples on here.

Comment: Can you give us an example what you'd like to do with this row/column number? To find a value in a matrix that is not just a single column or row, I'd usually use `SUMPRODUCT()` or dynamic array alternatives (or if possible a nested `MATCH()`). See [ask] a question with an [mcve] and edit your question.

Comment: Question edited. Could you be more specific with your suggested functions?

Comment: You have a very broad and cryptic description of your query. Many possibilities, but a valuable answer depends on what you want to do when you find this row/column. For example see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60283708/9758194) old question on SO.